# KML lat/lon to SVG or canvas?

Tags: svg, html5-canvas, kml

Is there a way to convert lat/lon coordinates to an SVG path or canvas tag path? I want to display state outlines in SVG on a map on the web. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

[D3.js](http://d3js.org/) offers a variety of nice map related functions along these lines.

See for example http://mbostock.github.com/d3/talk/20111116/airports.html